# ¿Cómo puedo obtener la suma de los números que se encuentran dentro de una cadena de texto con bucle for?

Tags: javascript

Necesito obtener la suma de los números que se encuentran dentro de una cadena de texto.

Al momento de ejecutarlo, lo que me imprime es el total del número que escribe el usuario, y lo que me gustaría saber es como obtener la suma de todos los números que se encuentra en la cadena, mi código es el siguiente:

```javascript
//TODO: esta función debe retornar la suma de todos los números que se encuentran en el parámetro `text` de tipo `string`

getNumberSum: (text) => {
    const cadenaN = text.split(' '); // ejemplo [HOLA12, 12, 3, CHAO]
    let sumNumber = 0;

    for (let i=0; i<cadenaN.length; i++){ 
        if(!isNaN(cadenaN[i])){ //verifica si el dato es un numero
            sumNumber = sumNumber + cadenaN[i];
        }
    }
    
    return sumNumber; //debe retornar la suma total
}
```

Comment: Cuando dices sumar todos los números, te refieres a sumar todos los dígitos o a los números tal como se encuentren, ejemplo  `Hf83k1t22` -> **(1)** `8+3+1+2+2` o **(2)** `83+1+22`

Comment: por ejemplo [HOLA12, 12, 3, CHAO]  seria 12 + 3 = 15

Comment: si, puedo usar lo que necesite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problema:

Estás concatenando cada elemento devuelto por el `split()` como cadenas de texto en lugar de sumarlos como números:

```
if (!isNaN(cadenaN[i])) { // verifica si el dato es un número.
  sumNumber = sumNumber + cadenaN[i];
}
```

Si hacemos un `typeof` a cada elemento, verás que todos (incluído los números de tu cadena) son de tipo `string`:

```js
// Obtener la suma de los numero que se encuentran dentro de una cadena de texto.
const getNumberSum = (text) => {
  //TODO: esta función debe retornar la suma de todos los números que se encuentran en el parámetro text de tipo string.
  const cadenaN = text.split(' '); // ejemplo [HOLA12, 12, 3, CHAO].

  let sumNumber = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < cadenaN.length; i++) {
    console.log(`${cadenaN[i]} => ${typeof(cadenaN[i])}`);
  }
}

getNumberSum("HOLA12 12 3 CHAO");
```

### Solución:

Debido a que en el `if` solo ingresan los números de tu cadena, debes convertir cada número a tipo numérico antes de sumarlos. Para esto, puedes usar la función [**`parseInt()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

```
if (!isNaN(cadenaN[i])) { // verifica si el dato es un número.
  sumNumber = sumNumber + parseInt(cadenaN[i]);
}
```

### Ejemplo:

```js
// Obtener la suma de los numero que se encuentran dentro de una cadena de texto.
const getNumberSum = (text) => {
  // TODO: esta función debe retornar la suma de todos los números que se encuentran en el parámetro text de tipo string.
  const cadenaN = text.split(' '); // ejemplo [HOLA12, 12, 3, CHAO].

  let sumNumber = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < cadenaN.length; i++) {
    if (!isNaN(cadenaN[i])) { // verifica si el dato es un número.
      sumNumber = sumNumber + parseInt(cadenaN[i]);
    }
  }
  return sumNumber; // debe retornar la suma total.
}

console.log(getNumberSum("HOLA12 12 3 CHAO"));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! me funciono correctamente :)

Comment: depronto con cadenaN.substring( i,i+1) =="0" || cadenaN.substring( i,i+1) =="1" || .....

Answer (score 1):

¿Qué tal?

Como ya te indicaron, el problema surge porque no es posible sumar directamente valores numéricos contenidos dentro de cadenas de caracteres. Cuando separas la cadena a partir de los espacios en blanco, obtienes *retazos* de la cadena original, los cuales componen un arreglo resultante. Por tal motivo, es necesario convertir los valores numéricos (contenidos en cadenas) a sus respectivos tipos numéricos, para lo cual JavaScript ofrece [muchas formas de hacerlo](https://dev.to/sanchithasr/7-ways-to-convert-a-string-to-number-in-javascript-4l).

El problema con el hecho de separar la cadena únicamente indicando un espacio en blanco (`" "`) es que, en caso hubiera dos o más espacios consecutivos, obtendrás cadenas vacías como parte del arreglo que devuelve el método `split()`:

```js
console.log("HOLA12  12 3 CHAO".split(" "));
```

El anterior ejemplo incluye dos espacios en blanco entre las cadenas `HOLA12` y `12`, lo cual derivará en este arreglo: `['HOLA12', '', '12', '3', 'CHAO']`. Mientras más espacios en blanco consecutivos haya, más cadenas vacías como parte del arreglo resultante habrá.

La solución para esto viene de la mano con el propio método `split()`, el cual acepta una [expresión regular](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_expressions) como parámetro. En este caso, la expresión regular puede ser la siguiente: `\s+`, lo cual indica que se tomará cualquier espacio en blanco, sea uno **o más**, para separar la cadena.

Trasladado a tu código, se vería así:

```javascript
const cadenaN = text.split(/\s+/);
```

En ejecución:

```js
console.log("HOLA12   12 3 CHAO".split(/\s+/));
```

De esta forma no tendrás que preocuparte de que en algún momento pudiera haber uno o varios espacios en blanco consecutivos presentes en la cadena. Aplícalo en la solución que te dieron para que evites ese tipo de inconvenientes.

---

**EDICIÓN:** Olvidé aclarar que la necesidad de hacer esto se debe a que, si se aplica la función `isNaN` a una cadena vacía, esta retornará `false` porque el motor de JavaScript interpretará a dicha cadena como un cero. Y si luego intentas aplicar la función `parseInt` a esa cadena vacía, obtendrás un `NaN` ([Not-a-Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN)), lo cual impedirá que puedas realizar la sumatoria.

Comment: muchas gracias por la explicación me ha quedado mas claro